# Local Path does not exist, gradle runtime error in new Android Studio 1

Tags: android, android-studio

I download new android studio virsion 1. and i installed it. But When i run my app then studio give me following image as you see error give me.
[image]

I have allready updated SDk. amd when i click sdk button in studio then sdk not open.its still not open. Somebody please help me. I gote this error last five days. My work was down. please help about this

Comment: please check if file is present at the oath you have specified.

Comment: Thanks Piyus for replay, but i cant find app-debug.apk file in my app workspace folder.And the app debug apk file not created when i run my project.I also re Download android studio and create new project different workspace, but error still. not leave. Please help about this, Thanks again men

Comment: Often click the "Sync with Gradle files" button in the toolbar, along with doing a clean and rebuild, will solve this problem.

Comment: Thank for replay brother. I Solved thet problem. Its not a Gradle problem. Its a My system environment problem in Countrol Panel. i Added just in under Control Panel>System>Advance System Setting>Environment Variable . And just add PATH entry and give it value is "%SystemRoot%\system32". without quota. This means problem in my system variable,That android studio cant understand.